# How often "-to-be" is added to nouns? is it ok to modify nouns this way?

Tags: nouns, hyphenation

I would like to use some noun and express plans about it in the future. Think, getting something.

I see "my bride-to-be" as a good example. It's better than using "wannabe." Can I add such tail to other nouns? I would like to avoid slang. Should I find better ways to express such meaning? Something for professional/business context?
As short/concise as possible.

Thank you for all feedback and sorry if it's a duplicate - just hard to search such question.

Comment: Very close: https://guinlist.wordpress.com/tag/noun-to-verb/

Comment: _Wannabe_ is modern slang, but expressions like _bride-to-be, mother-to-be_ are well-established.

Comment: @KateBunting, *wannabe X* is not only slang, but also implies that there may be doubts about the person's qualifications to be X (it implies that the person's eagerness to be X may be out of proportion to the person's qualifications for the role), while *X-to-be* implies that it is very likely that the person will in fact become X.

Comment: Just to be clear, **NOUN-to-be** indicates that the thing or person to whom the suffix is applied is not yet a NOUN but will soon become one.  So you seem to misunderstand how **-to-be** is used when you say, "I would like to use some noun and express plans about it in the future. **Think, getting something**". If you were to say "I'm looking forward to my *bicycle-to-be*" you'd be misusing it, if you had purchased a bike you saw at the shop but you might say *bicycle-to-be* if you had paid someone to fabricate a frame and build out the bike and the parts were still strewn on the workbench.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With nouns the most common usages are with family relations, particularly around parents or weddings. And some formulations like *president-to-be* are found in journalism where it's useful to be concise in describing the results of elections or other processes. Aside from that there are phrases like *yet-to-be* and *soon-to-be* where it modifies adjectives or adverbs. It's almost always used with people rather than inanimate objects. Those are the common uses, so anything else might be a bit odd, and you'd be better using an adjective like *future* or *upcoming* e.g. *my future boss*, *my future job*, particularly in more formal contexts.

In the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), the top ten are: *soon-to-be* (983 occurrences), *bride-to-be* (355), *husband-to-be, mother-to-be, wife-to-be, moms-to-be, mom-to-be, mothers-to-be, yet-to-be, parents-to-be*. Further down we get a few like *speaker-to-be* (32), *president-to-be* (19), *free-agent-to-be* (13), *sophomore-to-be* (11). *Free-agent-to-be* is largely used in sports journalism; others like *speaker-to-be* and *president-to-be* in political journalism.

You can add the suffix to anything you like, but it might come across as humorous or even derogatory compared to more formal terms, so it would be fine in casual contexts but should probably be avoided e.g. in business English.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a great answer. I got the idea.

Comment: Just a minor extra question: if it's about person's title: Domain-to-be Engineer ? - similar to President -to-be but different.

Comment: "aspiring" seems to be the best choice.

Comment: *Domain-to-be Engineer ?* Definitely not that.

Comment: The person is not 'going to be' a domain! It would have to be _Domain Engineer-to-be._

Comment: @jsw29: Bizarre. I was just about to post exactly the same comment. But seeing there are at least two of us thinking the same thing, I was emboldened to just go ahead and make the correction!